# Message Read/unread across multiple devices and browser window in Firebase

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I am using Firebase/ AngularFire to build a chat module.
I have to keep track of User Read message across multiple devices and display it as number of unread messages for a user .
User can have many conversations, each conversation is between two users only.
Same conversation can be opened over multiple tabs or multiple devices. i.e. User can be connected on the same conversation page on multiple devices/tabs.

When user comes to a conversation page increment the counter of user connected in the userstatus : conversations : conversationId : userId : count : 5 (numberOfOpenConversaitonPlaces) This shows how many windows user has open for the same conversation across multiple devices.
When a user leaves / closes the conversation page decrement count and delete reference if Count = 0 At this point we know user doesn't have any open pages with conversation.
This indicates if the user is connected/disconnected to a conversation on any device or window. 
If the user has an entry for the open conversation mark all messages sent to the user as read / seen 
Once user is connected to a conversation mark all messages within as seen

Is this a correct? should i be updating all whether the message is seen or unseen based on if the user has a conversation open in a window which might not even be used? Or should i not be updating based on open windows for the chat and only change status when the user is active on the window? How to manage that on multiple windows /devices ? Is there a way to use .info/connected in this case ?

```
{
  "conversations" : {
    "conversationID1" : {
      "dateCreated" : "",
      "messages" : {
        "messageID1" : {
          "sentDateTime" : "",
          "content" : "",
          "sentTo" : "",
          "sentBy" : "",
          "seen" : false
        },
        "messageID2" : {
          "sentDateTime" : "",
          "content" : "",
          "sentTo" : "",
          "sentBy" : "",
          "seen" : false
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "userstatus" : {
    "conversations" : {
      "conversationID1" : {
        "userID1" : {
          "count" : 5
        },
        "userID2" : {
          "count" : 3
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey did you ever figure out how to do message read receipts? If you haven't lets work on it together to figure out how to do it. If you have could you please help me out on how to implement something like this using firebase?

Comment: @BhavikP. you guys found the solution for this ??